# Show that if a homomorphism has a left and a right inverse, then it is an isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Let $⟨X,<⟩$ and $⟨Y,<′⟩$ be tosets.

> If $f : X \to Y$ is an order homomorphism and $g:Y →X$ and $h:Y →X$ are order homomorphisms and $g◦f=id_X$ and $f◦h=id_Y$, show that $f$ is an order isomorphism.

So I have the following at the moment:

Let $ x,y \in Y$.
Then, as $h$ is an order homomorphism, $h(x) < h(y)$. Also $h(x), h(y) \in X$.
Thus, applying $f$,  $f(h(x)) < f(h(y))$. Also, $f(h(x)), f(h(y)) \in Y$.
Thus applying $g$, $g(f(h(x))) < g(f(h(y)))$.

The order relation is preserved for all functions.

I can think of the following that I might have to do but not sure how.

Show the tosets are in fact wosets by the order relation somehow and apply the fact that if $g \circ f = id_x$ and $f \circ g = id_y$, and order is preserved, $f$ is a bijection, thus has unique inverse, so $g = h$ and there is a unique order isomorphism given by $f$.

Comment: The definition of "a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism" (whatever the category) is: there exists another morphism $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=id_X$ and $f\circ g=id_Y$. So here, all you need to prove is that $h=g$.

Comment: 1) Your "Let $x,y\in Y$" should be followed by "such that $x<y$". Anyway, I don't think this paragraph leads to anywere. 2) "the tosets are in fact wosets" my no means (assuming "wo" means "well ordered"). 3) There are good ideas in the rest of that last paragraph, but they need to be... well ordered ;-)

Answer (score 2):

(I changed your title because) this is not specific to the category of ordered sets, even less of totally ordered sets. In any category:

> If three morphisms $f:X\to Y$ and $g,h:Y\to X$ are such that $g◦f=id_X$ and $f◦h=id_Y$, then $g=h$ hence $f$ is an isomorphism.

Proof: $g=g◦id_Y=g◦(f◦h)=(g◦f)◦h=id_X◦h=h$.

Comment: I don't think this is what's being asked. I believe he is trying to prove that if a map is a categorical isomorphism then it is a bijection that preserves order.

Comment: @JohnDouma He tried various things erratically, but the question he (and we) had to answer was exactly that one (cf. beginning of his post).